# EVENTDATA() for DML Triggers?

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am looking to create an audit table for my database in Azure SQL Database. The best method I have across so far in order to do this is to use triggers.

I have created this trigger for now,

```
CREATE TRIGGER [my_schema].[trg_my_table]
ON [my_schema].[my_table]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[audit_table]
VALUES
('my_table', SUSER_SNAME(), GETDATE());
```

I am just logging the name of the person who performs the action and the date.

However, while I was doing my research, I came across the `EVENTDATA( )` function that can be used in DDL triggers. I was wondering if there is an equivalent to this for DML triggers? Or is there some other way that I can get this information for DML operations?

You can find more information on the `EVENTDATA()` function here,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eventdata-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: What sort of "event data" are you looking for for a DML statement..?

Comment: Well.. Everything that comes with this EVENTDATA schema would be preferred, but mainly the database name, table name, event type, login name and SQL query.

Comment: A DML trigger *belongs* to an object, so you know the database name and table name. As for the other information, you can get the type of DML statement by looking at the `inserted` and `deleted` objects, and you already know how to get the `LOGIN`. DML and DDL statements are *completely* different, and thuis so too are DDL and DML statements. DDL statements belong to a database, not an object, so the type of data is *completely* different. There is no `EVENTDATA` for a DML trigger, as it doesn't require it; you can't have object agnostic DML triggers..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such function (like EVENTDATA() for DDL) available for DML triggers and you **can't use EVENTDATA() for DML triggers**. You need to create standard `ALTER`, `INSTEAD OF` and `CLR` triggers for DML as you are already doing.

You can check the functionality of these triggers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/dml-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15#types-of-dml-triggers).